# Django Channels middleware use ORM

Tags: django, websocket, python-asyncio, django-channels

I have troubles checking the user token inside of middleware. I'm getting token from cookies and then I need to query database to check if this token exists and belongs to user that made a request.

**routing.py**

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import game.routing
from authentication.utils import TokenAuthMiddlewareStack

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': TokenAuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            game.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

**middleware.py**

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed
from rest_auth.models import TokenModel

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from django.db import close_old_connections
...
class TokenAuthMiddleware:
    """
    Token authorization middleware for Django Channels 2
    """

    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner


    def __call__(self, scope):
        close_old_connections()

        headers = dict(scope['headers'])
        if b'Authorization' in headers[b'cookie']:
            try:
                cookie_str = headers[b'cookie'].decode('utf-8')

                try:  # no cookie Authorization=Token in the request
                    token_str = [x for x in cookie_str.split(';') if re.search(' Authorization=Token', x)][0].strip()
                except IndexError:
                    scope['user'] = AnonymousUser()
                    return self.inner(scope)

                token_name, token_key = token_str.replace('Authorization=', '').split()
                if token_name == 'Token':
                    token = TokenModel.objects.get(key=token_key)
                    scope['user'] = token.user

            except TokenModel.DoesNotExist:
                scope['user'] = AnonymousUser()
        return self.inner(scope)


TokenAuthMiddlewareStack = lambda inner: TokenAuthMiddleware(AuthMiddlewareStack(inner))
```

And this gives me

```
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

I also tried the following approaches

```
async def __call__(self, scope):
    ...
    if token_name == 'Token':
        token = await self.get_token(token_key)
        scope['user'] = token.user
    ...

# approach 1
@sync_to_async
def get_token(self, token_key):
    return TokenModel.objects.get(key=token_key)

# approach 2
@database_sync_to_async
def get_token(self, token_key):
    return TokenModel.objects.get(key=token_key)
```

Those approaches give the following error

````
[Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'TypeError'>: 'coroutine' object is not callable
/Users/nikitatonkoshkur/Documents/work/svoya_igra/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/autobahn/websocket/protocol.py:2847:processHandshake
/Users/nikitatonkoshkur/Documents/work/svoya_igra/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/txaio/tx.py:366:as_future
/Users/nikitatonkoshkur/Documents/work/svoya_igra/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:151:maybeDeferred
/Users/nikitatonkoshkur/Documents/work/svoya_igra/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/ws_protocol.py:72:onConnect
--- <exception caught here> ---
/Users/nikitatonkoshkur/Documents/work/svoya_igra/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:151:maybeDeferred
/Users/nikitatonkoshkur/Documents/work/svoya_igra/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/server.py:206:create_application
]```
````

Comment: keep the get_token function outside the class and use await get_token(token_key) instead of await self.get_token(token_key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at the source code of `django-channels`, especially at how `SessionMiddleware` works and uses django ORM, I ended up writing my TokenMiddleware in a similar fashion.

```
class TokenAuthMiddlewareInstance:
    """
    Token authorization middleware for Django Channels 2
    """

    def __init__(self, scope, middleware):
        self.middleware = middleware
        self.scope = dict(scope)
        self.inner = self.middleware.inner

    async def __call__(self, receive, send):
        close_old_connections()

        headers = dict(self.scope.get('headers', {}))
        if b'cookie' in headers:
            cookie_dict = parse_cookie(headers[b'cookie'].decode("ascii"))
            token = cookie_dict.get('Authorization', '')
            token_name, token_key = token.replace('Authorization=', '').split()
            if token_name == 'Token':
                self.scope['user'] = await self.get_user_from_token(token_key)
                inner = self.inner(self.scope)
                return await inner(receive, send)

        inner = self.inner(self.scope)
        self.scope['user'] = AnonymousUser()
        return await inner(receive, send)

    @staticmethod
    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_user_from_token(token_key):
        try:
            return TokenModel.objects.select_related('user').get(key=token_key).user
        except TokenModel.DoesNotExist:
            return AnonymousUser()


class TokenAuthMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    def __call__(self, scope):
        return TokenAuthMiddlewareInstance(scope, self)


TokenAuthMiddlewareStack = lambda inner: TokenAuthMiddleware(AuthMiddlewareStack(inner))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it will work or not,but you can try

First write the get_token function outside the class.

```
   # approach 1
   @sync_to_async
   def get_token(self, token_key):
     return TokenModel.objects.get(key=token_key)
```

then in your async function write get_token() instead of self.get_token()

```
  async def __call__(self, scope):
     ...
     if token_name == 'Token':
        token = await get_token(token_key)
        scope['user'] = token.user
     ...
```

Comment: Nope, exactly the same result